# Change Values of Global Variable with $scope function

Tags: javascript, html, date, momentjs

I defined two global variables of type Date and within the function I change the values, but somehow after running the function, the values of global variables didnt take the new value.  What is the issue?
Thanks in advance!

```js
var value1 = new Date()
var value2 = new Date()
var $scope = self.ctx


$scope.settimes = function() {
value1.setSeconds(0)
value1.setMinutes(15)
value1.setHours(6)

value2.setSeconds(0)
value2.setMinutes(30)
value2.setHours(12)

}

console.log(value1)
console.log(value2) //value1 and value2 still have the same value =new Date() but not be assigned with the values within the function
```

```html
<button ng-click="settimes()">Change Time</button>
```

Comment: For me, *self.ctx* returns *undefined* so the script returns an error. You can set the time values in one go (and zero the milliseconds too): `value1.setHours(6, 15, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `console.log` needs to be inside the function.
The code will run top to bottom, you define the function then immediatly call the `console.log`. But the values only change after you click the button, so you need to check the values inside the function.

```js
var value1 = new Date()
var value2 = new Date()
var $scope = self.ctx


$scope.settimes = function() {
  value1.setSeconds(0)
  value1.setMinutes(15)
  value1.setHours(6)

  value2.setSeconds(0)
  value2.setMinutes(30)
  value2.setHours(12)

  console.log(value1)
  console.log(value2)
}

 //value1 and value2 still have the same value =new Date() but not be assigned with the values within the function
```

```html
<button ng-click="settimes()">Change Time</button>
```

Comment: If this answer has helped you, please consider 'accepting' it; This will mark your question as solved, and also reward both you and the answerer some reputation - [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)